# How to resize animation in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, animation, frame-rate

I want to draw an animation, the size of each frame is 500x500px but when I try to resize, the animation seems to rotate...

Here the code to load frames and create animation:

```
    Texture fireSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("fire_sheet.png"));

    TextureRegion[] fireFrames = new TextureRegion[4];

    fireFrames[0] = new TextureRegion(fireSheet,0,0,500,500);
    fireFrames[1] = new TextureRegion(fireSheet,700,0,1200,500);
    fireFrames[2] = new TextureRegion(fireSheet,1450,0,1950,500);
    fireFrames[3] = new TextureRegion(fireSheet,2250,0,2750,500);


    fireAnimation = new Animation(0.5f, fireFrames);
```

In draw method I resize the animation in this way:

```
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

        batch.enableBlending();
        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        currentFrame = Assets.fireAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);

        batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(), getY(), 200, 200 );

    }
```

So if I use:

```
batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(), getY() ); // WORKS!!! But too Big for me 500x500px
```

Instead if I use:

```
batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(), getY(), 200, 200 ); // Animation doesn't work properly
```

What Can I do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

I made a custom Class for you:

```
public class MyAnimation extends Animation {

    float scaleX;
    float scaleY;

    public MyAnimation(){
        scaleX=1;
        scaleY=1;
    }

    public void setScaling(float scale){
        scaleX = scale;
        scaleY = scale;
    }

    public void draw (float stateTime, Batch batch, float x, float y) {
        TextureRegion region = getKeyFrame(stateTime);
        batch.draw(region, x, y, region.width*scaleX, region.height*scaleY);
    }
}
```

You can use it as it is or customize it as you wish.

Comment: Isn't this technically the same solution as in the question, which doesn't work? The only difference in drawing I see is that you use products instead of hard coded numbers. That and the missing `true` parameter in `getKeyFrame`. This doesn't explain what went wrong, so the asker (or others who stumble on this via Google) doesn't learn much.

Comment: He asked "What can I do?", now "Why can´t I do it?". I have no idea why his code fails, but I know mine works (I use it every day).

Comment: That may technically be true, but I think the point of this site is to convey knowledge, and not just copy&paste solutions. I'd have to double check, but I think something to that extent is even somewhere in the rules or faq. That said, the question isn't a great fit for the site to start with, as it's kind of a "debug my code" question.

Comment: You might be right on that one. I should explain my solution. But I seriously can´t. I guess the difference is the "true" value? It´s the only difference I see, still can´t explain why mine works and his doesn´t. Sorry.